# Segmentation Fault C++

Tags: c++, graph, segmentation-fault

The input is in the following format

```
5
1 2  9.0
1 3 12.0
2 4 18.0
2 3  6.0
2 5 20.0
3 5 15.0
0
1 5
```

The first number is the number of vertexes in the graph. Then next lines up to 0 are the edges of the graph. With the first and second numbers being the vertexes and the third being how far the edge is between them. Trying to read in the data and store the edges into there locations in the List adjacency for that vertex. This example would make a graph with five vertexes with edges from 1 to 2&3. 2 to 4&3&1 etc.

I am getting a Segmentation fault after entering four numbers. The fault is happening on line myGraph.vertexInfo[p1].adjacency -> vertex=p2; where is starts trying to store the information. Why am I getting this fault?

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

struct ListCell
{
   ListCell* next;
   int vertex;
   double weight;

   ListCell(int v, double w, ListCell* nxt)
   {
      vertex = v;
      weight = w;
      next = nxt;
   }
};

typedef ListCell* List;

struct Vertex
{
   bool signaled;
   long distance;
   List adjacency;    
};

struct Graph
{
   int     numVertices;
   Vertex* vertexInfo;

   Graph(int n)
   {
      numVertices = n;
      vertexInfo  = new Vertex[n+1];
      for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      {
         vertexInfo[i].signaled = false;
      }
   }
};

//==============================================================
//                   readIn
//==============================================================
// 
//==============================================================

void readIn()
{
   int g;
   int p1;
   int p2;
   float edge;
   scanf("%i ", &g);

   Graph myGraph(g);
   scanf("%i", &p1);
   while(p1 != 0)
   {
      scanf("%i", &p2);
      scanf("%f", &edge);         
      myGraph.vertexInfo[p1].adjacency -> vertex=p2; 
      myGraph.vertexInfo[p2].adjacency -> vertex=p1;
      myGraph.vertexInfo[p1].adjacency -> weight=edge; 
      myGraph.vertexInfo[p2].adjacency -> weight=edge;
      scanf("%i", &p1);
   }
}
//==============================================================
//                   main
//==============================================================

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   readIn();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't go over your code but add checks to see if  anything in myGraph.vertexInfo[p1].adjacency->vertex is null. I have a hunch that myGraph.vertexInfo[p1].adjacency may be null. . .

Comment: -1 **Learn to use a debugger**

Comment: print your variables and see what commands crash it (the last command printed is the command that crashed the program)

Comment: @LoganMurphy while that's certainly a quick way to gain some insight into the state of your program it's also a dirty (and unreliable) way to gain some insight into the state of your program. DMG should learn to (a) review and step through his code to find bugs and (b) learn how to use the right tool for debugging: a debugger.

Comment: I did use a debugger that's how I knew where the fault occurred. It just slipped my mind about initializing the adjacency. People come here for help with learning if you are going to criticize do so in a constructive way. Instead of telling them they need to learn how to use a debugger tell them about the debugger and what it is used for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at what `adjacency` is:

```
struct Vertex
{
   bool signaled;
   long distance;
   List adjacency;    
};
```

And now let's look at what `List` is:

```
typedef ListCell* List;
```

So, `adjacency` is actually a pointer to a `ListCell`. That's fine, we can work with that. But before we can, we must make sure that `adjacency` actually points to something. The question then becomes what does `adjacency` point to in your code?

The answer is: who knows? You never make it point to anything, so it's pointing somewhere randomly. And what happens when you try to write to some random area of memory? Well, if you're *lucky*, you crash.

So, how do you solve this problem? Simple: initialize and manipulate `adjacency` correctly. You may wish to look into dynamic memory allocation in C++ and the standard library which provides a rather nifty and working implementation of a linked list.

Sidenote: you seem to treat `adjacency` as a linked list. However, you ought to note that `adjacency` is a pointer to a *node* in a linked list. Again, now would a great time to learn about [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).

Answer (score 1):

You are not following some of the fundamental principles of object construction and intialization for `Vertex`.

When you construct an instance of `Vertex`, there is nothing predictable about the values of the member data. I would suggest adding a default constructor that initializes the member data to something sane.

```
struct Vertex
{
   Vertex() : signaled(false), distance(0), adjacency(NULL) {}

   bool signaled;
   long distance;
   List adjacency;    
};
```

Once you do that, the constructor for `Graph` can be simplified to:

```
Graph(int n) : numVertices(n)
{
    vertexInfo  = new Vertex[n+1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `adjacency` pointer is uninitialized, so you run into problems when dereferencing it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your adjacency member:

```
Graph(int n)
{
    numVertices = n;
    vertexInfo  = new Vertex[n+1];
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        vertexInfo[i].signaled = false;
        vertexInfo[i].adjacency = new ListCell(i, 0.0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Arguably, most of (if not all of) that work should be done instead the `Vertex` constructor.

Comment: @NikBougalis: Yes, of course. As the index 0 element of the vector is never used and, obviously, could be better use a vector instead of a standard c array of Vertex, and so on. In my answer I try to follow the asker's logic ... only this and nothing more. However thanks for your advice.